# How to delay angular bootstrap until after a service call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a beginner on angular.  I've got a need to make multiple webservice calls and then bootstrap my model.  I've tried placing the following code inside my function that is executed after all webservices have run.

```
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
        myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.obj = model
        }]);

        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
        });
```

But I receive the following exception.

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

My code still works, but I want to get rid of the exception and more importantly learn how the angular code should be structured when the bootstrapping is delayed.

I don't know if this will help, but I'm including it in case.

```
    <div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
       <div ng-repeat="o in obj track by $index">
       </div>
       <input id="Model" type="hidden" value="{{obj}}" />
    </div>
```

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6tybn02d/2/

Comment: I'm concerned that my issue might be related to where this code is in my page.  It's in a function that is called after some webservices return data.  So there is around a seven second delay until this code is called.  I'd put together a fiddle, but I'm not sure how to emulate this delayed call outside my environment.  And like you demonstrated, if I just make the call immediately in a fiddle I always got it to work fine.

Comment: seems to be fine with delay also - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6tybn02d/4/

Comment: also make sure there are no `ng-app` attributes in the html markup

Comment: Hadn't seen your suggestion about ng-app as I was posting my answer.  That was it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found from earlier attempts to get it working that I added the following to the html tag.

```
ng-app="myApp"
```

When I removed it my error went away.  I believe this is how you would perform automatic bootstrapping, but since I needed delayed bootstrapping it was causing issues.  Here is a link for more information on the directive

[ng-app directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

If someone more familiar with angular could verify my understanding I would appreciate it.  Thank you Arun for your fiddle.