# angular(>2) bootstrap application after a http result?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have seen similar question in  in angular version 1.x [How to delay angular bootstrap until after a service call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229078/how-to-delay-angular-bootstrap-until-after-a-service-call)
but interested to achieve same thing in v> 2.x

and the below one also not going to solve bcoz we are having a view component for ui router .

[Angular 2 Bootstrap application from external data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319229/angular-2-bootstrap-application-from-external-data)

Comment: you want call Ajax call before bootstrap?

Comment: Yes I want to get some config object. before loading the sub components of AppComponent

Comment: I think this solution will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300116/angular2-load-configuration-from-backend-on-startup